# Square Connect API - SqPaymentForm Apple Pay

Tags: api, square-connect, applepay, square

I have problem enabling Apple Pay on site. I'm using https with valid certificate domain is registered in Square for apple pay payments. There is a callback method in js for enabled methods.

```
// SqPaymentForm callback functions
callbacks: {

    /*
     * callback function: methodsSupported
     * Triggered when: the page is loaded.
     */
    methodsSupported: function (methods) {

        var applePayBtn = document.getElementById('sq-apple-pay');

        // Only show the button if Apple Pay for Web is enabled
        // Otherwise, display the wallet not enabled message.
        if (methods.applePay === true) {
            alert('Apple Pay supported');
            applePayBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
    },
```

The method gets called but it never reaches inside of the if statement. Paying with card works just fine. So the iFrames get loaded into form properly and everything. I just can't make Apple Pay work. I'm loading the page in Safari on mac mini or in webview on iphone simulator. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you set up Apple Pay on your mac? (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204506) Also, are you running macOS 10.12 or later? (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also tried it on real device with card added and latest iOS 11. Now I'm thinking could my location be a problem since I'm in country which doesn't support apple pay